# What is Bitcoin SV?

Tags: bitcoin-sv

I was wondering what the difference between Bitcoin SV was from Bitcoin (BTC). And what, then, is Bitcoin Core? What are the main things that differentiate the two? Why is BSV the scam and BTC not a scam? Why is is wrong to call Bitcoin SV 'Bitcoin'? The answers I received originally were very subjective and biased. Leave the politics out of the answers.

Comment: _Bitcoin SV_ is an altcoin (likely **scam**), _Bitcoin Core_ is one of the "Bitcoin protocol" **implementation**. There are few other Bitcoin Implementations: btcd, Gocoin, Libbitcoin, Bitcoin Knots, Bcoin etc.

Comment: I see the downvote for my question...Are web applications built over the BTC blockchain?  I have used some web apps that implement the use of microtransactions in many different ways and there is actually data stored on chain and not just 'value'.  BTC seems to be used only as an alternate form of currency that has high transaction costs as well as slow transaction times.  I don't understand what makes BTC superior or what makes BSV seem like a scam.  I would really love to understand this a bit more.

Comment: 1. Website over blockchain makes no sense 2. Micro transactions are possible using layer 2 solutions like LN 3. For a decentralized network you need people using full nodes and if nodes have to sync useless "data" not everyone will be able to do it 4. BSV is a scam because of marketing, misinformation, people involved in it and their intentions etc.

Comment: Twetch.com is built with the plumbing of blockchain running below it. BSV is no more of a scam than BTC. People do not like hearing that their returns from BTC investments are made from a scam coin. So, I understand the feedback I have received here. Take politics out of it and see that BSV is electronic p2p cash system...not a store of value...not a security.

Comment: Why are my questions flagged while the answers that say BSV is a scam ok? BSV is now legally considered Bitcoin.

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity because Bitcoin Core is a piece of software, not a cryptocurrency.

Answer (score 7):

BitcoinSV is an altcoin, an alternative cryptocurrency and blockchain. It shares some blockchain history with Bitcoin but Bitcoin Cash (BCH) hard forked from Bitcoin and then BitcoinSV hard forked from Bitcoin Cash. It has made some highly dubious technical decisions and is associated with some discredited individuals.

Bitcoin Core is an implementation of the Bitcoin protocol. Some consider it Bitcoin's reference implementation. There are other implementations that attempt to maintain consensus with Bitcoin Core. BitcoinSV does not attempt to maintain consensus with Bitcoin Core.

Comment: that was much more insightful than the previous response.  thank you.